# How would you pass two arguments to the command line?

Tags: java

```
String input = "";
if (args.length>0)
{
  input=args[0];
}
```

I was able to use this method to write from the command line an pass one argument, but I'm unsure how to pass a second argument. Sorry for brief description unsure what else to say?

Comment: Take a look at [Oracle's Tutorial on Command Line Arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a standard `main()` method `args` will be an array so you can simply access the next index to get the next argument value:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String first = args[0];
   String second = args[1];
   ...
}
```

This works when you call java with the arguments separated by a space

```
java MyClass arg1 arg2
```

Comment: "*Normally `args` is an array*" - It always is (I will interpret a varargs as array aswell).

Comment: Unless we are outside of regular `main()` method and `args` was redefined, it's not clear based on OPs question.